# Oh no! SO Is down? Is it time for a tin foil hat so they can't read our brain?

Tags: support

[image]

StackOverflow isn't there anymore? Is this planned, or is this the default "*uh oh*" message?

EDIT: It's back, but what happened?

Although it says "*StackExchange is currently offline*", meta **wasn't**?

**To make the question more un-localized (so that it doesn't get closed by the cover-up crew ;))**, could someone elaborate on what exactly that message means? Does it mean that SO has had a hardware malfunction/is currently undergoing planned maintenance?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaand it's back, but it would be good to know what happened?

Comment: This site is part of Stack Exchange so that means the downtime is over seeing as you could post here. Edit - and your comment appeared after I posted this :3

Comment: It's oscillating

Comment: Too localized close votes coming up! :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's a conspiracy! You're a pawn in the cover up plan ;)

Comment: I saw that too. Rather weird.

Comment: @AshRj You saw nothing...NOTHING!...Understand!?!

Comment: @Bart I wont be quiet! I wont let the truth be buried for eternity!!

Comment: I liked the Times New Roman font.

Comment: @Asad Me too, that page must of taken at least 58 designers.

Comment: The original question was edited. +1 and flag for reopen...

Comment: Nice try, but it's still too localised.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I've flagged for reopen :)

Comment: @mat - why would you do that? `"This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a ... specific moment in time ..."`

Comment: @Lix There is **absolutely no way** that it will get another 4 re-open votes. If it did, I'd close it myself :)

Comment: If you aren't already wearing the hat, it's too late.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stay tuned to [StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) on twitter - notices of temporary outages are updated there regularly.

Make sure to check there **before** posting on meta - this "outage blip" *was* planned.

Answer (score 6):

From the source of the error page:

```
if we get here, that means even the offline pages on sstatic are offline
```

What you saw was a an outage that included the http://sstatic.net offline pages, wide enough for the *pretty* offline pages to not be available either. The fugly banner message is the backup to the backup.

It was a very brief outage, and it [was planned](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/316925303232528384). We can all remove the tin-foil hats and move along.

For reference, the full source of the error page is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>We are Offline</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        iframe { border: 0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" id="pageFrame"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function () { location.reload(true); }, 300000);
        var hostName = window.location.hostname;
        var directory = '';
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://sstatic.net/error-director.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (top == self && directory) {
            document.getElementById('pageFrame').src = 'http://sstatic.net/' + directory + '/app_offline.htm';
        } else {
            // if we get here, that means even the offline pages on sstatic are offline
            document.getElementById('pageFrame').style.height = "0px";
            document.write("<h2>Stack Exchange is currently offline, we'll be back shortly!<\/h2>");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is "sstatic"?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: The CDN, or content delivery network, for the static Stack Exchange components.

Comment: @ColeJohnson See http://sstatic.net/

Comment: Nice find. Do you have a permalink to the error page in question so we can see it ourselves?

Comment: @Chichiray: No, I was looking at the source myself *at the time*. I had copied that text to the Python chat room too, I didn't even have the source anymore at the time of my answer. From memory, it was preceded by a `<script>` tag loading JS from `sstatic.net`, and some JS code to test if that had loaded correctly.

Comment: One minute ago it occurred once again. I've for reference copypasted the source into your answer :)